# substr with strlen

Tags: php, substr, strlen

I have an amount like **0003000**, the last 2 digits are the decimal number. I want to transform  **0003000** to **00030,00** (insert a decimal comma in front of the last 2 digits). 
I tried to do this with substring. I take the length of the string with strlen and then I make -2, but it ignores the -2.

Here is an example, why is it being ignored?

```
substr($this->arrCheck['amountsum'],0,(strlen($this->arrCheck['amountsum']-2)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `-2` is in the strlen function instead of outside it:

```
strlen($this->arrCheck['amountsum']-2)
```

Should be:

```
strlen($this->arrCheck['amountsum'])-2
```

But all in all you don't need to use strlen, since substr accepts a negative number as number of characters before the end of the string: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

So your whole code above can be replace by:

```
substr($this->arrCheck['amountsum'], 0, -2)
```

And the whole thing can be achieved by:

```
substr($this->arrCheck['amountsum'], 0, -2).','.substr($this->arrCheck['amountsum'], -2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the strlen close bracket after the -2. Try:

```
substr($this->arrCheck['amountsum'],0,(strlen($this->arrCheck['amountsum'])-2))
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need `strlen()` in this case, try:

```
substr($this->arrCheck['amountsum'], 0, -2) . ',' . substr($this->arrCheck['amountsum'], -2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the folowing:

```
echo substr_replace("0003000", ",", -2, 0); // output: 00030,00

echo number_format("0003000" / 100, 2, ',', ''); // output: 30,00
```

Answer (score 1):

use number_format() instead. That will be easy to use.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use number_format

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

or correct your code.

```
substr($this->arrCheck['amountsum'],0,(strlen($this->arrCheck['amountsum']) -2))
```

you can't place -2 into strlen() function

Answer (score 0):

this way ?

```
substr($this->arrCheck['amountsum'], 0, -2).','.substr($this->arrCheck['amountsum'], -2);
```